# i need to remove prefixes using xslt-3and exclude-result-prefixes

Tags: xslt-3.0

input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mr:collection
    xmlns:mr="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim http://www.lc.gov/standards/mrxml/schema/mr21slim.xsd">
    <mr:rc>
    <mr:dtf tg="2000" i1="1" i2=" ">
        <mr:sbf cd="a">Christoph Kolumbus</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="d">John Diter</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="b">Julie Nat</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="f">Darius Milhaud</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Erich kleiber</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Franz Ludwig Horth</mr:sbf>
    </mr:dtf>
    <mr:dtf tg="3000" i1="1" i2=" ">
        <mr:sbf cd="a">Christoph Kolumbus</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="d">Serg</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="b">Mak</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="f">DarMil</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Erikl</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">LudHorth</mr:sbf>
    </mr:dtf>
</mr:rc>
<mr:rc>
<mr:dtf tg="2000" i1="1" i2="0">
    <mr:sbf cd="a">Chris Prante</mr:sbf>
    <mr:sbf cd="e">&quot;Chris Dietz&quot;</mr:sbf>
</mr:dtf>
</mr:rc>
</mr:collection>
```

with the following xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim"
xmlns:e="https://example.com"
xmlns:dc="https://examples.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
expand-text="yes"
version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="collection">
    <O-PM>
        <ListRcs>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ListRcs>
    </O-PM>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="rc">
      <e:rc>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </e:rc>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dtf[@tg = 2000]">
      <mdtd>
          <rc>
              <dc:title xml:lang="el">{sbf[@cd = 'a']} {sbf[@cd = 'b']}{sbf[@cd = 'e']!(':', .)} {sbf[@cd = 'f']!('/', .)}{(sbf[@cd = 'g'] => string-join(' ; '))!('', .)}</dc:title>
          </rc>
      </mdtd>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dtf[@tg != 2000]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we get

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<O-PM>
   <ListRcs>
      <e:rc xmlns:e="https://example.com">
         <mdtd>
            <rc>
               <dc:title xmlns:dc="https://examples.com" xml:lang="el">Christoph Kolumbus Julie Nat / Darius Milhaud Erich kleiber ; Franz Ludwig Horth</dc:title>
            </rc>
         </mdtd>
    
      </e:rc>
      <e:rc xmlns:e="https://example.com">
         <mdtd>
            <rc>
               <dc:title xmlns:dc="https://examples.com" xml:lang="el">Chris Prante : "Chris Dietz"  </dc:title>
            </rc>
         </mdtd>
      </e:rc>
   </ListRcs>
</O-PM>
```

how can one get <e:rc> instead of <e:rc xmlns:e="https://example.com">?

exclude-result-prefixes should work for literal result elements we create in our XSLT code... I need to declare namespaces and i am not getting the output i want.
ie <e:rc> instead of <e:rc xmlns:e="https://example.com">
and <dc:title xml:lang="el"> instead of <dc:title xmlns:dc="https://examples.com" xml:lang="el">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim"
xmlns:e="https://example.com"
xmlns:dc="https://examples.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
expand-text="yes"
version="3.0">
```

i.e. don't exclude the prefixes `e` and `dc` you declared for serialization you will get a root element declaring them e.g.

```
<O-PM xmlns:dc="https://examples.com" xmlns:e="https://example.com">
```

and content like

```
  <e:rc>
     <mdtd>
        <rc>
           <dc:title xml:lang="el">Christoph Kolumbus Julie Nat / Darius Milhaud Erich kleiber ; Franz Ludwig Horth</dc:title>
        </rc>
     </mdtd>
  </e:rc>
```